# Setting up spring boot project with liquibase

Tags: spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I have a spring boot 2 project(jhipster) and I am a little confused on how hibernate tables work with liquibase.

Right now I have a bunch of data classes with hibernate annotations and I would like to insert some static data for testing purposes. I have a bunch of questions in getting started.

Do I have to define liquibase `changeSets` to create tables when I already have the hibernate annotated data classes?

How do I run liquibase `changeSets` when configuring the database?

EDIT -----
How are the foreign key relationships named between the changeset and the domain(java) code? For example I have a `Person` table and it holds a reference to an `Address` table. How do I represent this relationship within the changeSet table?

The `Person` table doesn't hold an id of an `Address`, it holds the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Spring boot has excellent integration with liquibase.

If you want **liquibase to handle creation of the tables** (DDL) and not hibernate:

you need to disable the hibernate auto-create flag.

set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`
(or) remove this property from application.yml file.

Just include following into pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Below is the sample code to create tables and insert data into table.

> File location:
>   src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

```
  databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: sgollapinni
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: person
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: int
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: first_name
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: last_name
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
        - createTable:
            tableName: address
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: int
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: city
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: person_id
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                        nullable: false
                        foreignKeyName: fk_person_address
                        references: person(id)
  - changeSet:
      id: 2
      author: sgollapinni
      changes:
        - insert:
            tableName: person
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: first_name
                  value: Sunil
              - column:
                  name: last_name
                  value: Kumar
        - insert:
            tableName: address
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: city
                  value: Bangalore
              - column:
                  name: user_id
                  value: (Select id from person where name = 'Sunil')
```

Otherwise, if you want hibernate to handle the DDL and only you want to insert some static data for testing purposes, **you can still do this using liquibase**.

You can use **changeSets** to add the DML statements.

```
- changeSet:
  id: 1
  author: sgollapinni
  changes:
    - insert:
        tableName: person
        columns:
          - column:
              name: first_name
              value: Sunil
          - column:
              name: last_name
              value: Kumar
    - insert:
        tableName: address
        columns:
          - column:
              name: city
              value: Bangalore
          - column:
              name: user_id
              value: (Select id from person where name = 'Sunil')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have another question - how are the foreign key relationships named between the changeset and the domain(java). For example I have a `person` table and it holds a reference to an `Address` table. How do I represent this relationship within the changeSet table?

Comment: I have made changes to the answer with more details. Also, if you want to just specify the person to address foreign key relationships by liquibase changesets then do following:     
     <column name="user_id" type="int">  
         <constraints nullable="false" 
                foreignKeyName="fk_questions_author" 
                references="users(id)"/>
      </column>
If you want data then check details in above answer.